# How to backup octopress when I publish on Github

Tags: octopress

I launch my own octopress yesterday,
And our blog articles are stored under source  folder/
however when I run rake deploy , it only push the public data to github server.
because the default .gitignore are as following

```
  1
  2 .bundle
  3 .DS_Store
  4 .sass-cache
  5 .gist-cache
  6 .pygments-cache
  7 _deploy
  8 public
  9 sass.old
 10 source.old
 11 source/_stash
 12 source/stylesheets/screen.css
 13 vendor
 14 node_modules
```

Is there any better way to put your source markdown file in the GitHub server, to avoid I delete the source code accidently.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just make a repo in your GitHub account for the source, and push it there?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the gitignore file. Maybe your problem is with your git branch.

Try this `$ git branch` if it says `master` you have to rename the branch to source like this:

`$ git branch -m master source`

Then when you do `$ git branch` again it should say `source`

When you deploy you should git add, git commit then `$git push origin source` then `rake deploy`

Let me know if this works

Answer (score 0):

`rake deploy` will push changes in _deploy folder to master branch.

After `rake deploy`, if you do `git push origin source` under `~/octopress` folder then your posts will be pushed to the source branch of your repo.